# Curious integral pattern

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

While messing around with integrals and testing different values, I observed that the following seems to hold for any two functions $f(x),g(x)$:

$\int_0^L f(x)g(x)\,dx=\int_0^{L/2}2f(2x)g(2x)\,dx$

But I can't think of any applicable integration rules that would make this true. Does anyone have any ideas about how to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u = 2x$, $du = 2dx$ in the right hand side and perform substitution to get the left hand side. In short: it's the chain rule.